# RecyclerView Load data only once

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I noticed that every time I scroll up/down my RecyclerView, the "onBindViewHolder" is being called and my data (Textviews and Imageviews) is being refreshed/reloaded in the background.

Is there a way I can tell the RecylerView to not refresh or reload, upon scrolling, a specific textview for example? Is there a method I need to override or something?

Comment: recyclerview show items you should to see, if you can see 10 items in your screen and have 100 items in data list, recyclerview not bind all items and only bind items you can see,

Comment: It is called RecyclerView for that reason if you want it to not recycle use a listview.

Comment: can you try putting  viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false); in your onBindViewHolder method. maybe it will do the work for you

Comment: @Mohammad Tabbara, i guess you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up achieving my goal by implementing some logic to check and control if values exist upon scrolling. I couldn't find other straight forward ways because as @Mohammad Tabbara said, this is how RecyclerView works by design.

Answer (score 1):

Use SrcollDisabled RecyclerView

```
public class ScrollDisabledRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {
    public ScrollDisabledRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ScrollDisabledRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ScrollDisabledRecyclerView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Use it inside xml like this

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <com....ScrollDisabledRecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

`RecyclerView` only creates as many as view it needs to full fill the screen, and as its name says, it recycle or reuse the views it created by calling the `onBindViewHolder`, so that behavior is pretty normal.

If you need an specific position not to be recycled, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42209168/how-to-make-recyclerview-stops-recycling-defined-positions) question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
yourAdapter adapter = new yourAdapter( , , );
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```